# Using @use and @forward - scss file with @media inside, is injected at the top of css code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I'm using **VSC** with **Live Sass Compiler** from Glenn Marks.

I'm trying to import code from scss file where are written @media for my project. All seems to work almost perfect, but this @media code is injected at the very top of my main.css file, and I would love it to be at the very end. Is there any option to do this with @use and @forward?

EDIT: File structure.
I have one folder "scss/utilities" with 5 scss files + one file "_index.scss" with only forwards inside. main.scss is outside, in folder "scss"

Main scss file is called "main.scss", at the top I call this folder by "@use 'utilities' as *;"

As I said, code is pulled to the css file, but the only problem is that @media from files "01_small_", "02_medium", "03_large" are injected at the beginning of the css code.

[FILE STRUCTURE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW75u.png)

Comment: How / where do you use and forward stuff, how is your SCSS file structured? How do you implement media-queries? It all boils down on how you set up and structure your project.

Comment: @cloned I have updated post with more info. Thank You!

Comment: Where are the mediaqueries defined? What do you do where you expect the media-queries to be rendered at the bottom? There are multiple ways of creating mediaqueries in SCSS.

Comment: I have managed to inject it by mixin, but I'm not sure if it is a optimal choise.

Comment: I still don't know in which file you used the mixin and how you use this file then in the other files. Why do you think your mixin should be rendered last? It will be rendered wherever you use it.

Comment: I have nothing but few lines of code in file "sass/utilities/03_large.scss" which looks something like `@media (min-width: 992px) {   background-color: #232323; } `. Then I pull it to "sass/main.scss" by `@use 'utilities' as *;`

Comment: So if I understand this correctly you use it as the first line in your SCSS. Why do you expect it to render last?

Comment: As far as I know `@use` have to be called at the beginning. `@import` was the one that could be called later.

Comment: Let's rephrase my question: What are you doing that makes you believe your media-queries should be rendered in the end? They won't get rendered magically where you want them, you have to tell SCSS how / where it should do it. Where do you do this? How do you expect this to work?

Comment: This is why I put this question. If I would know the answer, question would be not necessary.

Comment: You can't just put any piece of code anywhere and expect it to work like you want it to magically. Either you post more code here and explain why you think it should work you expect or you read up on how to use SCSS. There are 100 different ways to use it, all I can say for now with the limited info I have is: Change your setup to produce the output you want. Have you tried just putting your `use` in the end of the file? Does that work?